# Images use too much RAM in Processing

Tags: java, image, memory, processing

I'm trying to load a few thousand small images into processing and display them as a larger map. The total filesize of the images together is 130MiB however when I run the program it uses all of my RAM and I even get an `OutOfMemoryError` as the RAM usage exceeds 2GiB.

What causes over 10x the memory usage compared to the filesize, and is there any way I can mitigate this?

EDIT:

Example code

```java
ArrayList<PImage> images = new ArrayList<PImage>();
void setup() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000 /*num of images*/; i++) {
        images.add(loadImage(Integer.toString(i) + ".jpg");
    }
}

//in reality, never gets here
void draw() {

    for (PImage i: images) {
        image(i, /*precalculated x and y*/ random(500), random(500));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Alright adding one now

Comment: It could be black magic, who knows without the code.

Comment: JPEG compression ratio is 10:1, so that would explain it: the images are compressed on disk, but when loaded into your program and decompressed you get 10 times the size.

Comment: @jbx added an example

Comment: @mnistic That's probably the issue then.

Comment: Images are typically unpacked in memory for easier processing.   Can you process one at a time and forget about each when done ?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen the problem with that is that I'd need to load every image every time `draw()` runs, and that'd be VERY slow. Less than 1/10 fps.

Comment: Well, if you do not have the memory to hold all the unpacked images, you need to unpack when you need them.  If that is too slow then you may need to rearchitect.  You are familiar with tiling technologies like DragonZoom?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen no I'm not. I eventually decided to downscale the images at runtime which does slow down the loading but it allows for dynamic changes in the resolution and thus memory usage as and when needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPEG compression ratio is 10:1, so that would explain it: the images are compressed on disk, but when loaded into your program and decompressed you get 10 times the size.

To improve your code, don't load the images all at once: process them few at a time.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way I can process them a few at a time because I need to draw them all at once (they're map segments and I need to draw the whole map). But that does explain why. I'll accept in a sec

Comment: Don't keep in memory more than fits on the screen (a couple of hundred MB). Load and discard segments as they come in and out of the view.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do and it works fine when zoomed in, but the problem arises when you zoom out (sometimes it's necessary to see the whole map at once). I think what I'll do is resize the images if not zoomed in to hopefully reduce ram usage.